# Как правильно выровнять <div> по центру страницы?

Tags: html, css

Кто знает как разместить див по центру страницы, я пробовал несколько способов но  оставался в верхнем левом углу. Что я делаю не так?
html код:

```css
h1{
    font-family: Arial Black,Arial Bold,Gadget,sans-serif; 
}

h4{
    margin-top: -60px;
    font-family: Arial Black,Arial Bold,Gadget,sans-serif; 
}

pre{
    margin-bottom: -40px;
}

#field{
    width: 300px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    height: 30px;
}

.btns{
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

#footer{
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
        <div id="main">
            <pre>
                <h1>MSearch </h1>
                <h4>Convenient search engine</h4>
            </pre>
            <input id="field" type="search" placeholder="To find what?"><br>
                 <img class="btns" src="img/google.png">
                 <img class="btns" src="img/yahoo.png">
                 <img class="btns" src="img/bing.png">
                 <img class="btns" src="img/yandex.png">
                 <img class="btns" src="img/youtube.png">
                 <img class="btns" src="img/wikipedia.png">
                 <img class="btns" src="img/msn.png">
         </div>
    <div id="footer">
    <footer>
        MultiSearch:copyright: - All rights reserved.<br>
        2021 - 2021
    </footer>
    </div>
```

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
div{
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }
```

```html
<div> text </div>
```